# Get Multiple itemprop values with xPath and PHP inside a DIV for wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xpath

I have the following code

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content">
 <h3 itemprop="name">Grab this text</h3><div itemprop="description">Grab this text too</div>
</div>
```

How can I grab both those text parts and place them inside variables?
I'm working in WordPress, building a plugin. There are multiple itemprops on the page that I don't want, so I can't select just those.

I've tried

```
$name = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="content"]//h3[@itemprop="name"]' );
```

But that doesn't select the second part description and leaves me with an error when I try to echo it.

I think I might have to iterate through them after grabbing the main div, but I'm not sure how to do that, and I looked up a few other stacks that didn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filter of `@itemprop` inside `div[@class="content"]` is enough, use this:

```
$name = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="content"]/*[@itemprop]' );
```

If you are only interested in `@itemprop` with the value 'name' or 'description' use this:

```
$name = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="content"]/*[@itemprop[.="name" or .="description"]]' );
```

The `*` means any `element`, so it will find both `h3` and `div`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Siebe, your answer partly helped, so I didn't accept the answer I wanted to post what the difference I found making it work.

I got the name and description separate.

```
//div[@class="content"]//@itemprop[.="name"]
//div[@class="content"]//@itemprop[.="description"]
```

Thanks for the idea of the .= that's what I was missing.